# CakePHP static name of controller

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm probably missing something really obvious here, but is there a function in `CakePHP` (I'm on 3.8) that returns the name of a controller without creating an instance of the class?

An instanced controller can call this function:

```
echo $this->name;
```

But what I'd like to be able to do, is avoid typing the controller name as a string in, say, an `HTML->link()`; ie a static call something like:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    'Dashboard',
    ['controller' => DashboardsController::name, 'action' => 'index']
);
```

The reason is that I'm refactoring a couple of controllers and am having to find and replace all of those strings by hand. I come from a `.Net` background and `CakePHP` is pretty new to me, so if there's a better (more cakeish) way to carry out the refactoring than the question I'm asking, then I'd be really glad to hear it.

Nothing in the documents is leaping out at me, but I've a feeling there should be a simple answer.

Comment: You could always create such a constant on your controllers yourself. Also you may want to look into named routes, which are easier to refactor if required at all. **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#using-named-routes**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace of a class can be retrieved using `::class` property. Checkout the following example:

```
 DashboardsController::class // Cake/Controllers/DashboardController
```

The name without the namespace can be retrieved with `ReflectionClass`:

```
$function = new \ReflectionClass(DashboardsController::class);

var_dump($function->inNamespace());
var_dump($function->getShortName());
```

Shortname can be used to get the class without namespace:

```
namespace App;

class Test {
   public static function name(){
      $function = new \ReflectionClass(self::class);

      return $function->getShortName();
   } 
}

var_dump(Test::name());
```

Checkout the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php#example-186
Reflection: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getname.php

Comment: Thanks for that. I could use the `::class` property and extract just the controller name from the string. I guess I was hoping there might be a Cake solution which avoided the substring function. For example, `$this->name` would return just `Dashboard` instead of `DashboardController`.

Comment: I added a example method you could use. Then you can subtract `Controller` by default. There is no default method for that @Ambie